# react className conditional setting according to all of state

Tags: reactjs, if-statement, state

I currently making a vocabulary website and got state from mysql, and the state is like this.

```
1: memorize : 0
2: memorize : 0
3: memorize : 0
4: memorize : 0
5: memorize : 1
6: memorize : 0
```

So if I check the checkbox on the list of website, each state turns  to 1. and 0 means not checked. every time check the box, it changes the value of state(from0 to 1)

and what I want to make is the button(finish) that active&disable. If all of the state turn in to 1, I want to make this finish button active.
So I decided to make 2 className, active, notActive, however it is really hard to make the condition.

How to use "If" structure to examine all state? I have tried using State.map, but this only works when examine each state, not whole.

in conclusion, I want to make

```
  useEffect(() =>{if( all of the state === 1){ buttonClassName = active}}
```

could you tell me how to embody"all of the state" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your state is an object with numbers as keys, and with a value with structure like `{memorize: 0}` .

I'd do something like these to get a boolean with said conditions:

```
const active = Object.keys(state).every(key => state[key] && state[key].memorize === 1);
const buttonClassName = active ? 'active': 'notActive';
```

[every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) function is an easy way to get a boolean from an array, or in this case, an object.

I also recommend you take a look to [useMemo](https://usehooks.com/useMemo/) hook. Seems like it would save you logic and renders in this particular case.